# How to solve this eqation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a transcendental equation which contains a parameter theta. When I solve the equation with theta free, I get 8 solutions which all have the expression (theta-1) in the denominator. So they blow up. I do not see a cause for that in the equation.If instead I first replace theta with 1, then I get good finite solutions. There must be something I am doing wrong here, and I would appreciate help in identifying it.
In the code below I deleted output because all the typesetting will look awful on the forum.

```
expr = Sqrt[θ Cos[ϕ]^2 + (-a + θ Sin[ϕ])^2]

(* all solutions have a factor (θ-1) in the denominator so they \
blow up there *)
sol1 = ϕ /. Solve[y == expr, ϕ] // Simplify

(* But if I substitute θ\[Rule]1 first, all is well *)
Solve[y == expr /. θ -> 1, ϕ]

(* Solve cannot handle this at all*)
sol2 = ϕ /. 
   Solve[y == expr && 0 < θ < Pi && 0 < a < θ, ϕ] //
   Simplify
```

Comment: About the first part of your post: imagine $ax^2+bx+c=0$. The solutions are $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$, which blow up at $a=0$, but there is no "cause for that in the equation". So your first solution is valid for $\theta\neq 1$, and the second is for the particular case $\theta=1$. That's all.

Comment: You should use `Reduce` with appropriate assumptions rather than `Solve`.  Nonetheless the system should be more restrictively determined, i.e. `Reduce[y == expr && 0 < θ < Pi && 0 < a < θ, ϕ]` doesn't yield solutions in a reasonable time. Could you explain what do you solve `y == expr` for? Introducing another variable `y`  doesn't yield especially interesting knowledge.   Remarks by `corey979` are correct, and it is not clear what you are expecting for.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try Reduce. The reason I am solving this is I want to invert the relation to one defining phi[y, theta, a] for further use.

Comment: Thanks to all. My main difficulty was a typo, where Sqrt[θ Cos[ϕ]^2 + (-a + θ Sin[ϕ])^2] should have been Sqrt[θ^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 + (-a + θ Sin[ϕ])^2]. With that, Solve works fine. Although I have had difficulty getting Reduce to work as well. This is not unusual for me. There seem to be many users here and on the Wolfram forum who are much better at working with Reduce than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround using "Halbwinkelsubstitution"(sorry I don't know the english word):

If you substitute  `\[Phi] -> 2 ArcTan[u ]]` you'll get

```
expru = Sqrt@FullSimplify[TrigExpand[  \[Theta] Cos[\[Phi]]^2 + (-a + \[Theta]  Sin[\[Phi]])^2 /. \[Phi] -> 2 ArcTan[u ]]]
```

which can be solved for u

```
solu = Simplify@Solve[expru == y, u];
```

Resubstituting u gives you all branches

```
solu /. u -> Tan[\[Phi]/2]
```

of the solution `\[Phi]` !

In contrast to the three Solve-variants (question) this way of solution avoids the warning `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.`

Comment: Google translate returns `half angle substitution` for `Halbwinkelsubstitution`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think 'Tangent half-angle substitution' is the term I wasn't aware.